# cleveref -- using both abbreviated and full form references?

Tags: cross-referencing, cleveref

> The words *chapter, part, appendix, table, figure,* and the like are lowercased and spelled out in text (though sometimes abbreviated in parenthetical references).

*(Chicago Manual of Style, 16th ed., section 8.178)*

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\begin{document}

\section{Geometric abstraction}
\Cref{myfig} shows a black square. For a black square, please refer to \cref{myfig}. Squares can be black (cf.\ \cref{myfig}).

\begin{figure}
    \centering 
    \includegraphics[width=6cm,height=6cm]{fig1.pdf}
    \caption[asd]{Kazimir Malevich. \textit{Black Square.} 1915. Oil on canvas. State Russian Museum, St Petersburg.}
    \label{myfig}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

**MWE produces:**
[image]

**What I am looking for:**
[image]

Is there a clever (sorry) way to achieve this with `cleveref`? I know that `\Cref{}` will always produce the full form, capitalized reference, so that is a good start. But how would I handle the non-parenthetical reference in mid-sentence?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is another approach requiring less delving in to the innards of `cleveref`.  The idea is to change the name locally using `\crefname`.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[noabbrev]{cleveref}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\abbrevcrefs}{%
\crefname{figure}{fig.}{figs.}%
\crefname{equation}{eqn.}{eqns.}%
}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\cshref}[1]{{\abbrevcrefs\cref{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\section{Geometric abstraction}

\begin{equation}
  \label{eq:x}
  x = 1.
\end{equation}
\Cref{myfig} shows a black square. For a black square, please refer to
\cref{myfig,eq:x}. Squares can be black (cf.\ \cshref{myfig,eq:x}).
Back to \cref{myfig,eq:x}.

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=6cm,height=6cm]{fig1.pdf}
    \caption[asd]{Kazimir Malevich. \textit{Black Square.} 1915. Oil on canvas. State Russian Museum, St Petersburg.}
    \label{myfig}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

We load the `cleveref` package with the `noabbrev` option to get all the full name versions.  We provide a list of abbreviated forms encapsulated in a command `\abbrevcrefs` and then define a new command `\cshref` for abbreviated references that calls `\cref` proceeded by `\abbrevcrefs` and enclosed in a group to make the effect local.

The same general approach could be used to make modified versions of other commands from the `cleveref` package.

I had hoped to be able just use the internal `\@cref@abbrevtrue` locally to turn on abbreviations, but it turns out that `cleveref` only uses this switch when initially defining the label names, not when typesetting them.  The label defining process is hooked in to `\AtBeginDocument` code, and can not be easily reevaluated to extract the abbreviated versions, hence the need to set up the abbreviations oneself.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I think I found a solution -- but it is neither elegant nor clever ;-)

I defined a new command `lcCref`, which will always give a lowercase, full form reference and will also handle plural references correctly:

```
\usepackage{xstring}
\def\lcCref#1{%
    \StrCount{#1}{,}[\n]%
    \ifnum\n>0\relax%
        \StrBefore[1]{#1}{,}[\myFirst]%
        \lcnamecrefs{\myFirst}~\labelcref{#1}%
    \else%
        \lcnamecref{#1}~\labelcref{#1}%
    \fi%
}
```

First, the number of arguments are counted. If a single label is referenced, the outputs of `lcnamecref` and `labelcref` are combined (see `cleveref` doc). If there are multiple references, `lcnamecrefs` is used instead of `lcnamecref`. The `StrBefore` construct is needed because `lcnamecrefs` only accepts a single label as an argument.

`\lcCref{myfig}` will result in `figure 1`, whereas `\lcCref{myfig,anotherfig}` will result in `figures 1 and 2`.

I have the feeling that this might be overly complicated. But it seems to works ...

Comment: Well ... this doesn't really work in all situations. `\lcCref{mytable,myfig}`, for example, will not work. Also, my hack really takes away from the flexibility of `cleveref`, as the things cannot be overridden by a global option.