# Cleveref - use both abbreviations and full reference names

Tags: cleveref

I was wondering if it is possible to use both options (full reference name and abbreviations of reference names) in the `cleveref` package.

The case at hand is a document containing both references within text mode and references above `=` signs in math mode (e.g. in the example below). Ideally, I would like to use the full reference name (Theorem 0.1) in text mode, while using the abbreviated version (Thm. 0.1 or something like that) in cases like `$\stackrel{\text{\Cref{th:theorem1}}}{=}$` for reasons of the space required for printing the reference above the `=` sign.

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Below is a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,english]{scrbook}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[nameinlink, noabbrev]{cleveref}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[chapter]
\newtheorem*{theorem*}{Theorem}

\begin{document}
\begin{theorem}\label{th:theorem1}
If $A$ is closed, then $A$ is closed.
\end{theorem}
\begin{proof}
Left to the reader.
\end{proof}

In \Cref{th:theorem1} we have seen that ...

\begin{equation}
a + b \stackrel{\text{\Cref{th:theorem1}}}{=} 0\,.
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The solution presented in [cleveref — using both abbreviated and full form references?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/183462/134144)  should also work in your case. Please also be aware, that `\Cref` will always result in the non-abbreviated form.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out! I have modified so that it works with both `\Cref` and `\cref` in abbreviated and non-abbreviated form.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to leandriis for giving the hint: [cleveref -- using both abbreviated and full form references?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/183462/cleveref-using-both-abbreviated-and-full-form-references)

This modified solution works for both `\Cref` and `\cref` in abbreviated and non-abbreviated form:

```
\usepackage[nameinlink, noabbrev]{cleveref}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\abbrevcrefs}{%
\Crefname{theorem}{Thm.}{Thms.}%
\Crefname{example}{Ex.}{Exs.}%
\crefname{equation}{eqn.}{eqns.}%
}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\Cshref}[1]{{\abbrevcrefs\Cref{#1}}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\cshref}[1]{{\abbrevcrefs\cref{#1}}}
```

I hope it will be helpful.