# How to get full forms with namecref and abbreviated forms otherwise?

Tags: cleveref, german

Continuing [cleveref -- using both abbreviated and full form references?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/183462), how to get full forms as an output of `\namecref` and `\nameCref` while maintaining the abbreviated forms from `\cref` and `\Cref` as usual?

Example:

```latex
\documentclass[ngerman]{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[ngerman,capitalize]{cleveref}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  Irgendein Diagramm% German for “Some diagram”
  \caption{Bezeichnung des Diagramms}% German for “name of the diagram”
  \label{fig}
\end{figure}
Betrachen wir \cref{fig}. %%% German for “Let us consider Fig. 1.”, which is fine.
Diese \namecref{fig} beschreibt \ldots %%% German for “This Fig./Figure describes …”. We'd like to have an unabbreviated form here: “Diese Abbildung beschreibt …” (German for “This figure describes …”). “Diese Abb. beschreibt …” (German for “This Fig. describes …”) looks strange.
\end{document}
```

produces

> Betrachen wir Abb. 1. Diese Abb. beschreibt …

We'd like to have a more pleasant

> Betrachen wir Abb. 1. Diese Abbildung beschreibt …

instead.

If possible, we would NOT like to change the part `\begin{document}…\end{document}`, i.e., the names of the used commands such as `\namecref`, `\cref`, and others because there'd be a huge LaTeX document to adapt – a long book. Ideally, the only changes should happen in the preamble, or, at worst, `\namecref` can be replaced with something else because there are only few instances of `\namecref` in the book (as opposed to many instances of `\cref` and `Cref`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could temporarily switch to the long form:

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[ngerman,capitalize]{cleveref}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\namecref}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \crefname{figure}{Abbildung}{Abbildungen}%
  \crefname{subfigure}{Abbildung}{Abbildungen}%
  \@setnamecref{cref}{#1}{}{}%
  \endgroup
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  Irgendein Diagramm
  \caption{Bezeichnung des Diagramms}\label{fig}
\end{figure}
Betrachen wir \cref{fig}. %%% “Betrachen wir Abb. 1.” is fine.

Diese \namecref{fig} beschreibt \ldots %%% We'd like to have an unabbreviated form here: “Diese Abbildung beschreibt …”. “Diese Abb. beschreibt …” looks strange.

Betrachen wir \cref{fig}. %%% “Betrachen wir Abb. 1.” is fine.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Working on Shabbat is a bad habit, but thank you very much anyways! I was unaware of `\@setnamecref` before.